# How to sync 2 shares on LastWriteTime without deletion

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, copy-item

I need to synchronize 2 FTP repertories behind 2 different servers which are not member of a cluster IIS. A virtual IP is used to do have a kind of failover.

[image]

I tried with robocopy or xcopy needs to have a reference directory. In my case, when the task is launched by a third server, I just need to copy the last written files and directory which are not in the other one.

```
$Global:pathFTP1 = $SRV1unc + "\c$\inetpub\PlcmSpIp"
$Global:pathFTP2 = $SRV2unc + "\c$\inetpub\PlcmSpIp"
$Global:Files1 = @()
$Global:Files2 = @()
$Global:tSRV = @(
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{Serveur = $SRV1; RacineFTP = $pathFTP1; Fichiers = $Files1}
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{Serveur = $SRV2; RacineFTP = $pathFTP2; Fichiers = $Files2}
)
```

Here is a part of the code:

```cs
$Global:Component = "Tree"
$Comparison = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $tSRV.Item(0).Fichiers -DifferenceObject $tSRV.Item(1).Fichiers -PassThru -IncludeEqual
$ComparisonFolders = $Comparison | Where-Object{$_.PSIsContainer -eq $true}
$FoldersPresentOnEach = $ComparisonFolders | Where-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "==") -and (Test-Path($_.FullName))}
$FoldersNotPresentInSRV1 = $ComparisonFolders | Where-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>") -and (Test-Path($_.FullName))}
$FoldersNotPresentInSRV2 = $ComparisonFolders | Where-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=") -and (Test-Path($_.FullName))}
##Folders not present on $SRV1
if ($FoldersNotPresentInSRV1.Count -ne 0) {
    foreach ($Folder in $FoldersNotPresentInSRV1) {
        if (-not (Test-Path (($Folder.Fullname.Replace($SRV2unc,$SRV1unc)).Replace('\\\','\\')))) {
            New-Item -ItemType Directory -Path (($Folder.Fullname.Replace($SRV2unc,$SRV1unc)).Replace('\\\','\\')) -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
       }
    }
}
##Folders not present on $SRV2
if ($FoldersNotPresentInSRV2.Count -ne 0) {
    foreach ($Folder in $FoldersNotPresentInSRV2) {
        if (-not (Test-Path (($Folder.Fullname.Replace($SRV2unc,$SRV1unc)).Replace('\\\','\\')))) {
            New-Item  -ItemType Directory -Path (($Folder.Fullname.Replace($SRV1unc,$SRV2unc)).Replace('\\\','\\')) -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
        }
    }
}

##Files comparison
$ComparisonFiles = $Comparison | Where-Object {$_.PSIsContainer -eq $false}
$FilesPresentOnEach = $ComparisonFiles | Where-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "==")  -and ($_.LastWriteTime -eq (($_.Directory.Fullname.Replace($SRV2unc,$SRV1unc)).Replace('\\\','\\')).LastWriteTime)}
$FilesNotPresentInSRV1 = $ComparisonFiles | Where-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "=>") -and ((Test-Path($_.Directory.Fullname.Replace($SRV2unc,$SRV1unc)).Replace('\\\','\\')))}
$FilesNotPresentInSRV2 = $ComparisonFiles | Where-Object {($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=") -and ((Test-Path($_.Directory.Fullname.Replace($SRV2unc,$SRV1unc)).Replace('\\\','\\')))}
## Files not present on $SRV1
if ($FilesNotPresentInSRV1.Count -ne 0) {
    foreach ($File in $FilesNotPresentInSRV1) {
        Copy-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination (($File.Directory.Fullname.Replace($SRV2unc,$SRV1unc)).Replace('\\\','\\')) -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
##Files not present on $SRV2
if ($FilesNotPresentInSRV2.Count -ne 0) {
    foreach ($File in $FilesNotPresentInSRV2) {
        Copy-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination (($File.Directory.Fullname.Replace($SRV1unc,$SRV2unc)).Replace('\\\','\\')) -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
$Global:Component = "Files already present"
if ($FilesPresentOnEach.Count -ne 0) {
    foreach ($File in $FilesPresentOnEach | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -gt (Get-Item(($_.FullName.Replace($SRV1unc,$SRV2unc)).Replace('\\\','\\'))).LastWriteTime}) {
        Copy-Item -Path $File.FullName -Destination (($File.Fullname.Replace($SRV1unc,$SRV2unc)).Replace('\\\','\\')) -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue       
    }
    foreach ($File in $FilesPresentOnEach | Where {$_.LastWriteTime -lt (Get-Item(($_.FullName.Replace($SRV1unc,$SRV2unc)).Replace('\\\','\\'))).LastWriteTime}) {  
        Copy-Item -Path (($File.Fullname.Replace($SRV1unc,$SRV2unc)).Replace('\\\','\\')) -Destination $File.FullName -Force -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
}
```

I expect that the files where the attribute LastWriteTime the more recent is copied on the other one it already exist and older or if doesn't exist.
Actually some folders are not copied and it doesn't work as expected.

Instead of rewrite the path with some `replace`, how can I do it properly?
Maybe I take the problem in the wrong way and do it with another tool?

Comment: Run `robocopy` twice (once for either sync direction).

Comment: You're meaning that `robocopy ($SRV1unc + "\c$\inetpub\PlcmSpIp") ($SRV2unc + "\c$\inetpub\PlcmSpIp")   
/E /ZB /X /COPYALL /XO /FFT` and `robocopy ($SRV2unc + "\c$\inetpub\PlcmSpIp") ($SRV1unc + "\c$\inetpub\PlcmSpIp") /E /ZB /X /COPYALL /XO /FFT` will do the trick ?

Comment: I would expect it to, yes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Why make it simple when you can make it complicated - Shadoks*

Thanks to Ansgar Wiechers, using Robocopy without mirror option is the simpliest way to achieve the task.

```
robocopy $pathFTP2 $pathFTP1 /E /ZB /X /COPYALL /XO /FFT /LOG:$ficROBOCOPY
robocopy $pathFTP1 $pathFTP2 /E /ZB /X /COPYALL /XO /FFT /LOG+:$ficROBOCOPY
```

I have to deal now with a gMSA account to launch the task and this kind of error :

> System.Management.Automation.ParameterBindingArgumentTransformationException:
>   Cannot process argument transformation on parameter 'Value'. Cannot
>   convert value to type System.String. --->
>   System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTransformationMetadataException:
>   Cannot convert value to type System.String. --->
>   System.Management.Automation.PSInvalidCastException: Cannot convert
>   value to type System.String.    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute.Transform(EngineIntrinsics
>   engineIntrinsics, Object inputData, Boolean bindingParameters, Boolean
>   bindingScriptCmdlet)    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>   at
>   System.Management.Automation.ArgumentTypeConverterAttribute.Transform(EngineIntrinsics
>   engineIntrinsics, Object inputData, Boolean bindingParameters, Boolean
>   bindingScriptCmdlet)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.ParameterBinderBase.BindParameter(CommandParameterInternal
>   parameter, CompiledCommandParameter parameterMetadata,
>   ParameterBindingFlags flags)    --- End of inner exception stack trace
>   ---    at System.Management.Automation.ExceptionHandlingOps.CheckActionPreference(FunctionContext
>   funcContext, Exception exception)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.ActionCallInstruction`2.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)    at
>   System.Management.Automation.Interpreter.EnterTryCatchFinallyInstruction.Run(InterpretedFrame
>   frame)

But it is another problem...