# Robocopy, ScheduledTask and gMSA

Tags: powershell, scheduled-tasks, powershell-2.0, robocopy, gmsa

Using a [powershell script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56169667/how-to-sync-2-shares-on-lastwritetime-without-deletion) with robocopy launch by [gMSA](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askpfeplat/2012/12/16/windows-server-2012-group-managed-service-accounts/) is not working ...

I write a little script to copy 2 directories in powershell with robocopy and it works.
I use it with the task sheduler, with a normal account, it works.
But doing the same with a gMSA, does'nt work

```bsh
$logfile = "C:\Scripts\SyncFTP\Logs\SRV-IIS-1.txt"
$options = @("/E","/ZB","/X","/COPYALL","/XO","/FFT",("/LOG:" + $logfile))
$args = @("$pathFTP2","$pathFTP1",$options)
robocopy @args
```

Here is the log file of Robocopy when it is launch with gMSA :

```
ERROR : Invalid Parameter #10 : "C:\Scripts\SyncFTP\Logs\SRV-IIS-1.txt"
```

It is like the `$logfile` was not correct only when it is launched by gMSA...

Have you got some ideas ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6338015/how-do-you-execute-an-arbitrary-native-command-from-a-string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case, i do it like this :

```bsh
Invoke-Expression "& robocopy $pathFTP2 $pathFTP1 /E /X /COPY:DATSO /XO /FFT /LOG:$logfile"
```

It seems to work now , before the [WE](https://lesjoiesducode.fr/quand-je-parviens-a-corriger-un-bug-juste-avant-de-partir-en-week-end) ^^